# iTunes does not recognize folder structure when importing music

Tags: itunes, music, itunes-match

I have imported a lot of Music into iTunes in a folder structure:
`<Artist>/<Album>/<Song>`. Unfortunately iTunes has not recognized these information, so that now I just have a lot of songs without artist or album information. (Actually I think that these has always worked until now). 
Do you have any idea what went wrong here and what I could do, to get this information into iTunes (and the iCloud)?

Comment: iTunes recognises the tags put into the mp3 or similar files and not the file structure, you need to fins a tool that will tag the music - this will depend on which OS you are on

Comment: I'm on OSX Lion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Doug's AppleScripts for iTunes](http://dougscripts.com/) are a good place to start looking for any iTunes scripting solutions.

In your case [Tags Mirror Artist-Album-Filename](http://dougscripts.com/itunes/scripts/ss.php?sp=tagsmirrorartalbfnom) looks very promising:

> This script copies the names of the Artist folder, Album folder and filename (minus its extension) of the selected tracks' file paths to each corresponding track's artist, album and song name tags, respectively.
>
> For best results your files and folders should be arranged in this format:
>
> Artist folder / Album folder / filename.xxx

Answer (score 0):

Select some songs (an album or songs from one of your previous folders) r-Click, select 'New playlist from selection'.  And a new playlist in your ipod is created..  [image]